# Setting value of different JSON key to field Play framework

Tags: java, sql, json, playframework, ebean

I am creating a REST service in play framework and I have a route which reads JSON from request. JSON is in this format:

```
{
"email":"test@test.com",
"password":"pw",
"address":{
"city":"cityName",
"country":"countryName"}
}
```

Then I use `user = Json.fromJson(json, User.class);` to parse JSON into user class. In my database, I have to tables with one to one relation which look like:

User:

```
EMAIL VARCHAR,
NAME STRING
```

Address:

```
EMAIL VARCHAR,
CITY VARCHAR,
ADDRESS VARCHAR
```

where EMAIL is foreign key.

Since the JSON i receive has only 5 values, when play framework saves the new record to database,in Address it saves only CITY and ADDRESS, and the EMAIL field is saved as null. And later on I can not retrieve the value of Address item of related User record since the foreign key which connects them is saved as null. (These are sql queries: )

Is there some annotation or some other way how I can use the email value from JSON as email value in Address table?

Here is how I wrote my Model classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User extends Model{
    @Id
    @Column(length = 80)
    private String email;
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String password;
    @OneToOne(cascade =  CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = Address
public class Address extends Model{
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "email")
    private User user;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String city;
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String country;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try saving **Address** first, later when object **Address** was managed by **ORM** set object address to object User and persist object User.

Something like this:

- parse JSON to User object
- get **Address** from **User** object parsed.
- Persist **Address** object
- set **Address** object to **User** object again
- Persist **User** object.

I hope this could help.

Comment: Thank you, I was a little 'blind' not to see that solution. I was thinking that there is some way to solve it with using annotations, and I didn't think of other possibilities.